# Корректное добавление данных в localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Делаю добавление

> localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'myValue');

Если по какой то причине не получится сохранить данные, как это отследить чтоб не поломалась остальную логика скриптов?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по [спецификации](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-storage-setitem) при выполнении `setItem` может произойти исключение, в случае если превышен размер хранилища, либо хранилища вообще отключены (например, в iOS выше 5 версии в private mode).

Отловить исключение можно воспользовавшись конструкцией [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
try{
    localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'myValue');
}catch(e){
    // что-то пошло не так
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понял что в catch я могу для себя вывести сonsole.log статуса ошибки, а если у пользователя например будет превышен размер хранилища, то элемент  localStorage не создастся и продолжится выполнения следующих скриптов?

Comment: @Shperung, выполнение скриптов продолжится